# Is this a safe way to extend this wiring?

Tags: wiring, junction-box

The picture below is just above our cooker extractor hood  underneath the first floor floorboards.
I need to bring through the 140mm diameter ducting from the extractor hood. I need to do this  in the top left of the picture next to the ceiling joist and wall due to the location of the hood.
One of the The diagonal wires in the picture is completely taught and so is right in the way.

The only way I can think of to deal with this is to cut the wires,  wire me end into a junction box fixed in the bottom left of the picture. Connect the other half of the wire into another junction box fixed in the bottom right and run a short length of new wire between the two junction boxes thus describing 2 sides of a square.

I’ve no complex electrical experience but this seems simple and logical to me.

Is there anything I am missing or which I need to take account of?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Will this space under the floor boards remain open so you will be complying with code that says a junction box *must remain accessible.* ? Will the boxes be accessible from the cabinet space below ?

Comment: Is the wire copper or aluminum? What size?

Comment: From your description I believe you are on the other side of the pond. The code being referenced by jack and Alaska man are from the NEC. I would guess it would be similar but would want to verify with someone local.

Comment: If you can follow that wire out of the pictured area, there might be some extra slack elsewhere, which you can pull through and save yourself some work. It's worth a shot, if you haven't tried already.

Comment: Thanks all, helpful comments. Alaska man- this space is under the upstairs floor boards and will be carpeted so I’m guessing that doesn’t qualify as accessible? if the ducting was removed from below then you could get at a junction in the top left of the picture from the room below but the 2nd junction needs to be away from the 14cm hole. Any ideas? I can’t install a panel in the ceiling it would look weird so is my only option to try and replace the whole run of wire? I don’t think that’s viable as I think it runs under a carpeted. I’ll check for slack though as Tungsten Wizard suggests.

Comment: Yes I’m in the UK.

Comment: Consider Wago connectors (and a box for tidiness)... they tend to make a better connection than a typical junction box and they have the added benefit of not needing to remain accessible as is required for junction boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a pretty good job of answering your own question. It will work. Get the right cable to box connectors. You might want to just connect the two junction boxes with some 1/2" conduit and get the appropriate size wire and color from you home store and shove them through the conduit. If all the wire will be copper, use approvd connectors. If the existing cable is aluminum then you'll need the appropriate connectors, like Alumiconn connectors.

Like Alaska Man mentioned above, the junction boxes will have to remain accessible forever.

If it is determined that the locations will not be accessible, then your solution would be to replace the run of cable to locations that are accessible.

Remember to turn off the power before doing any cutting...

Comment: Wire nuts are very uncommon in the UK... and I’m not sure they satisfy the UK wiring “regulations”.

Comment: @John Absolutely right John. That info came out after my answer.  not only are they uncommon, I don't think they are allowed. Thanks.